# asp.net mvc entity data framework - when adding an item it tries to add another item even theres no relation

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net-entity-data-model

I was encountring an error when I try to add class to the database

```
DB.Trips.Add(trip);
```

I **solved** it by setting the navigation properties to null, but i never had to do that before and it worked just fine, so im wondering why is that, as it doesnt seem to me as a good approach and the problem might persist.

When I do the DB.SaveChanges(); I get an error. From the SQL profiler I found out that it is trying to insert a record into Countries table.

```
exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[Countries](......
```

But Trips table doesn't even have Country property. There is a City property, which has Country. But why would it try to add that as well and how can I force it to insert only into Trips table ?

The data comes in via angular $http.post, is it possible its somehow related ?

Trip class city related attributes

```
 public int CityOriginID { get; set; }
 public int CityDestinationID { get; set; }    
 public virtual City CityDestination { get; set; }
 public virtual City CityOrigin { get; set; }
```

City class

```
public partial class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a reference to your Trip entity in your City entity like

```
public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips {get; set;}
```

to indicate your one-to-many relationship

Comment: I had it like that - navigation properties in my entity data model, but then I got problems with Json serializing. In the view im using angularJS, but the error is when i return JSON from the controller. this is the error.

    Self referencing loop detected with type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Trip_1521F4589BD8DFB07BA950E05E4B6029B3E847C1CAB6F4F1F8DCBAE7C9EF8544'. Path 'tripsList[0].cityDestination.tripsDestination'.

Comment: @user3549969 hmmm, try adding another reference just like the one above. public virtual ICollection<Trip> Trips1 {get; set;} Now, you should have two collections of Trip